How to correctly update 2 different parts of an object in session state?
In my TypeScript React project, I maintain a session state via unstated-next.  It has worked well for me up until now, but I've encountered an issue which I need help with.
Here's the session object definition:
  const defaultSession: SessionType = {
    user: {
      dateCreated: new Date(0),
      dateDeleted: null,
      email: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      mediaCount: 0,
      userId: '',
      userName: '',
    },
    common: {
      mediaSets: null,
      tagSets: null
    }
  };

I've built several helper functions to update various parts of this session object.  updateMediaCount updates the user's overall media count.  updateMediaSetCount updates the count of a specific mediaSet.  When called in isolation, they work fine.  But if both are called within the same function then things go awry.  Here's an example of the code that needs to be called if a media file is deleted:
sessionContainer.updateMediaSetCount(item.mediaSetId, currentMediaSetCount - 1);
sessionContainer.updateMediaCount(user.mediaCount - (mediaIdsToDelete?.length ?? 0));

In this example, the first function call works fine.  It's important to note that it is working with the current version of sessionContainer.  But when the second function call is made, it is ALSO using that original version of sessionContainer and not the new version of it, updated via the first function call.
Due to the async lag time, sessionContainer is not updated in time when the second function is called.
My immediate thought to fix this is to build a new helper function that updates BOTH sections of the object, something like updateAllCounts.  But I'm not sure if that is the best approach.
